# Correct Process for Determine Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}$$

a ratio test will evaluate to $1$, which means it can not be determined from this test. Clearly $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{9n^2}$ will be smaller, but by a comparison does not show anything. I am stuck.

Comment: You can evaluate this sum exactly by solving for $a,b$ that solve $\frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)} = \frac{a}{3n-2} + \frac{b}{3n+1}$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, then using a telescoping sum.

Comment: @Michael: However, each of these diverges.

Comment: @Bernard No, use  $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^k$.  You can calculate $\sum_{n=1}^k$ exactly via the telescoping sum.

Comment: I see. *A priori*, one might think it would be longer, but here, it happens it's sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n-1)}=\frac{1}{9n^2-3n-2}=\frac{1}{(3n-1)^2+3(n-1)}\le\frac{1}{(3n-1)^2}\le\frac{1}{9(n-1)^2}$. So using comparison test the series converges absolutely and now apply whatever methods to compute this.

Alternatively, as everyone suggested just use the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^m$. In this case sum of first $m$-terms is $-\frac{1}{3(3m+1)}-\frac{1}{6}$ so the limit exists and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

Since $$\frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)} = \frac 13 \cdot\frac{(3n+1)-(3n-2)}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}=\frac 13 \left(\frac{1}{3n-2} -\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)$$ Your sum equals $$\frac 13 \left(1-\frac 14+\frac 14-\frac 17+\frac 17-\frac{1}{11} \cdots \right)$$ which telescopes, and equals $$\frac 13$$This implies the sum converges.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use *asymptotic equivalence*, since this is a series with positive terms:
$$\frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}\sim_\infty\frac1{9n^2},$$
and the latter is a convergent $p$-series.